# When limit distribution of $\min(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n) - a_n$ is non-trivial?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions

Let $\xi_1,\xi_2\dots$ independent and identically distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$ and $\zeta_n = \min(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$.

Find such constants $a_n$ such that limit distribution of $\zeta_n - a_n$
is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

As in the OP: $\zeta_n = \min(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$. [The distribution function, $F_{\zeta_n}$, of the minimum of $n$ independent random variables of the common distribution function $F(x)$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed) is $$P(\zeta_n<x)=F_{\zeta_n}(x)=1-(1-F(x))^n.$$
Let ${a_n}$ be sequence of real numbers and consider the distribution function of $\zeta_n+a_n$, $$P(\zeta_n-a_n<x)=P(\zeta_n<x+a_n)=F_{\zeta_n}(x+a_n)=1-(1-F(x+a_n))^n.$$
Subtracting  a number from $\zeta_n$ shifts $F_{\zeta_n}$ and it does not changesits shape. So if the limiting distribution, $F_{\infty}(x)$ exists and if the sequence $a_n$ converges to, say, $a$ then the limiting distribution of $\zeta_n$ will be $F_{\infty}(x+a)$.

If 
$$
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,& \text{ if }& x<0\\
x,& \text{ if }& 0\le x\le 1\\
1,& \text{ if }& x>1
\end{cases}
$$
then the limiting distribution exists, and it is trivial; it is a jump from $0$ to $1$ at $0$ and
$$
F_{\zeta_n}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,& \text{ if }& x<-a_n\\
1-(1-(x+a_n))^n,& \text{ if }& -a_n\le x\le 1-a_n\\
1,& \text{ if }& x>1-a_n
\end{cases}.
$$

In this case, the limiting distribution is trivial if the limit of the sequence $a_n$ exists. (It is a jump at $-a$.) If $a_n$ does not converge then the limiting distribution does not exist.